# how to echo an image with given dimensions in php

Tags: php, html, image, echo, src

I am trying to echo an image but I need to display it with specific dimensions. The dimensions I have are already in $height and $width variables. 
Here is what I am trying to do.

```
<?php if (!empty($txt)) echo '<img src = "frame.png" alt = "rectangle" style = "width:$width; height:$height" />' ?>
```

Comment: Did you add "px" inside width and height variables? i forget everytime :))

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to concatenate strings in PHP.

If you use single quotation `'` then you have to concatenate like this

```
$string = 'Hi '.$variable;
```

If you use double quotation `"` then you can concatenate like the previous example or like this

```
$string = "Hi $variable";
```

So edit your code like the following and hope your problem will be fixed.

```
if (!empty($txt)) echo '<img src = "frame.png" alt = "rectangle" style = "width:'.$width.'px; height:'.$height.'px;" />';
```

Also don't forget to use `px` with height and width.